# Character controllerで移動する際、移動する方向にキャラクターを向かせてもすぐに戻ってしまう。

Tags: c#, unity3d

### わからないこと

キャラ移動させる際にLookRotation()でキャラの向きを指定しているのですが、立ち止まった際にZ方向へ向きを元に戻してしまいます。解決策やアイデアがありましたらお教えいただければ幸いです。

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public float walkSpeed;    // 歩く速さ
    public float runSpeed;     // 走る速さ

    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero; // 移動する量
    private Vector3 direction;                    // 移動する方向
    private float x;                              // horizontal
    private float z;                              // vertical
    private float gravity = 98f;                  // 下方向への移動量
    private CharacterController controller;       // character controller



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // character controller 取得
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        // GetAxisを定義
        x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        direction = new Vector3(x, 0, z); // GetAxisから方向を取得

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(1)) {  // 右クリックしながら移動するとダッシュ
            moveDirection = direction * runSpeed;
        } else {
            moveDirection = direction * walkSpeed;
        }


        // 地面についていなかったら下方向に落ちる
        if(controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection.y = 0f;
        } else {
            moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // 移動する
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        // ここが問題のよう。移動中は回転するのだが、移動し終わると元の向きに戻ってしまう。
        Quaternion q = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, q, 1200.0f * Time.deltaTime);


    }
}
```

### 試してみたこと

- Lookrotationの部分を変えてみる

  ```
  Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;
  Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
  transform.rotation = rotation;
  ```

  だめでした。
- moveDirectionを引数に入れてみる

  ```
  Quaternion q = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
  ```

  だめでした。
- x, zが入力されていないとき、returnする

  ```
      if(x == 0 && z == 0) {
          return;
      } else {
          direction = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
      }
  ```

  行けるかと思いましたが、returnしてしまうとそれ以降の処理がされないので、空中で立ち止まると落下しなくなるようになってしまいました。

Answer (score 1):

returnにすると処理が止まってしまうので、if文にしました。

```
    if(x != 0 || z != 0) {
        direction = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
    }
```

こうすることで、「x, z が0ではない(入力されている)ときに、direction を更新する」という処理になり、立ち止まっていても方向がもとに戻ることなく、また、着地判定も継続して処理され、落下するようになりました。